# Jhipster show origin translate

Tags: java, angular, jhipster

Can i set translator show origin message when not found.

ex: show

> User not found

instead of

> translation-not-found[User not found]

note: Only when not found translate. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to implement your own MissingTranslationHandler to replace the default one?https://github.com/jhipster/ng-jhipster/blob/master/src/language/jhi-missing-translation.config.ts

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I tried to do this but `MissingTranslationHandler` only gets the translation key and is responsible for returning the string that replaces the content of the element. Any idea? besides implementing a custom translation service.

Comment: Good point @vicpremir. I  think the only solution is to write your own directive because it has access to the element content, the pipe can't do it for instance. See https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/master/projects/ngx-translate/core/src/lib/translate.directive.ts